# Replacing elements in a list of lists with values from a dictionary or dataframe

Tags: python, replace, nested-lists

I have a list of lists that contains 8 elements in each list

```
list_of_lists = [
[123456789, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Conf', 'Clock Employee'], [124356789, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk HOL', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Faculty 10mo', 'Hourly NonExempt Employee'], 
[987654321, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd', 'Fixed 54hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Faculty 12mo', 'Salary Exempt Employee'], 
[456789123, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd HOL', 'Fixed 58hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College  Full Time Staff', 'Hourly Supervisor']]
```

I have a dataframe that has a list of titles and corresponding values to be assigned.

```
df = 
                                0      1
0                   Hourly 30 brk  100.0
1               Hourly 30 brk HOL  101.0
2              Hourly 30 brk wknd  102.0
3          Hourly 30 brk wknd HOL  103.0
4               Salary 30 brk HOL  104.0
12                 Fixed 4hrs HOL  100.0
13   Fixed 4hrs HOL no Winter Rec  101.0
14                Fixed 54hrs HOL  102.0
15  Fixed 54hrs HOL no Winter Rec  103.0
16                Fixed 58hrs HOL  104.0
17  Fixed 58hrs HOL no Winter Rec  105.0
18                 Fixed 5hrs HOL  106.0
19   Fixed 5hrs HOL no Winter Rec  107.0
20                Fixed 75hrs HOL  108.0
21  Fixed 75hrs HOL no Winter Rec  109.0
22                 Fixed 8hrs HOL  110.0
23   Fixed 8hrs HOL no Winter Rec  111.0
24                        Eastern  100.0
```

I need to be able to:

1. Loop through each row in the df, looking at first column of titles,
2. look in the list of lists for that title
3. replace the value in the list with the corresponding value.

tried below to confirm the values would be correct to look for:

```
for i in df[0]:
 print(i) # confirmed this pulls back the values i want to search for in index
```

this is where i get lost with code but can explain it.
I am searching for the title in the elements of the lists, once it's found, i want it to replace with `df[1]` value of `i`

So, the first df value of `'Hourly 30 brk'` would be used to look in the lists and found in the first list, location 3.  I then need to replace `'Hourly 30 brk'` with its corresponding value of 100

i'm not sure if creating a dictionary of the df is better for this or not because i can't comprehend how to do the replace from a different df.

Expected output:

```
list_of_lists = [
[123456789, 0, 'Y', '100', '100', '100', 'College Full Time Conf', 'Clock Employee'], 
[124356789, 0, 'Y', '101', '101', '100', 'College Full Time Faculty 10mo', 'Hourly NonExempt Employee'], 
[987654321, 0, 'Y', '102', '102', '100', 'College Full Time Faculty 12mo', 'Salary Exempt Employee'], 
[456789123, 0, 'Y', '103', '103', '100', 'College  Full Time Staff', 'Hourly Supervisor']]
```

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: What are the names of the df columns?

Comment: the names are just 0 and 1.  0 has the title, 1 has the values, edit: added the column names

Comment: So you want `df[df[0] == value_from_list][1]` to get the corresponding value in the df.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, df as dictionary works fine.

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_lists = [
    [123456789, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Conf', 'Clock Employee'], 
    [124356789, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk HOL', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Faculty 10mo', 'Hourly NonExempt Employee'], 
    [987654321, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd', 'Fixed 54hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College Full Time Faculty 12mo', 'Salary Exempt Employee'], 
    [456789123, 0, 'Y', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd HOL', 'Fixed 58hrs HOL', 'Eastern', 'College  Full Time Staff', 'Hourly Supervisor']]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {0: ['Hourly 30 brk', 'Hourly 30 brk HOL', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd', 'Hourly 30 brk wknd HOL', 'Salary 30 brk HOL', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL', 'Fixed 4hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Fixed 54hrs HOL', 'Fixed 54hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Fixed 58hrs HOL', 'Fixed 58hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Fixed 5hrs HOL', 'Fixed 5hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Fixed 75hrs HOL', 'Fixed 75hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Fixed 8hrs HOL', 'Fixed 8hrs HOL no Winter Rec', 'Eastern'], 
     1: [100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 100.0]})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    title = row[0]
    value = row[1]
    for sublist in list_of_lists:
        for j, item in enumerate(sublist):
            if item == title:
                sublist[j] = value

print(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: this works great!  can you briefly explain the for loops for me so i can comprehend what you did in relation to my data?

thank you so much!

Comment: I'm assuming you are not familiar with iterrows() method. It's hard to explain it in words because it's a broad topic. This method creates a tuple and we can access index and row directly.

Comment: More here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html